# How to show the hidden partitions in Ubuntu 14.04 installation?

Tags: windows-7, linux, partitioning, installation, ubuntu-14.04

I have a computer with Windows 7 and I am trying to install Ubuntu 14.04 alongside Windows. I have a 320GB harddisk partitioned like this:

```
DISKPART> list volum

::N volume::::Ltr::::::Nom::::: Fs:::::Type::::::Taille::::::Statut::Info
Volume 0 ::G Disque loca NTFS Simple 9 G Sain Fichéchg
Volume 1 E HP_TOOLS FAT32 Simple 103 M Sain
Volume 2 D RECOVERY NTFS Simple 16 G Sain
Volume 3 NTFS Simple 199 M Sain Système
Volume 4 C NTFS Simple 251 G Sain Démarrag
Volume 5 F DVD-ROM 0 o 0 média
```

But in the Ubuntu installation, it shows something similar to this (the same as from Windows 7 command prompt):

Showed partitions in CMD and Ubuntu installation

```
DISKPART> list disk
N° ::disque ::Statut :: Taille :: Libre :: Dyn:: GPT
•Disque 0 :: En ligne :: 298 G octets :: 19 G octets *

DISKPART> select disk 0
Le disque 0 est maintenant le disque sélectionné.

DISKPART> list partition
N° partition :: Type :: Taille :: Décalage
Partition 1 :: Données dynamiqu :: 992 K :: 31 K
Partition 2 :: Données dynamiqu :: 199 M 1024 K
Partition 3 :: Données dynamiqu :: 251 G :: 200 M
Partition 4 :: Données dynamiqu :: 46 G :: 251 G
```

I am installing Ubuntu using DVD.

How may I fix the problem using Windows 7 (show the partitions like in WDM), because when I try the Ubuntu command `fixparts` (in the "Try Ubuntu" terminal), it fixed the problem, but when I rebooted the computer, I found nothing changed.

Comment: Did you install using wubi using the windows installer? Or did you resize the partition and then do an install by booting a disk or USB key?

Comment: Please confirm. as suggested by your first DISKPART command and its response, if you are using GPT.  GPT is only necessary for hard drives larger than 3TB, and some Linux partitioning tools will not work with GPT. More information may be found at http://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/730440-using-the-new-guid-partition-table-in-linux-good-bye-ancient-mbr- https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/300415 and http://www.howtogeek.com/193669/whats-the-difference-between-gpt-and-mbr-when-partitioning-a-drive/

Comment: i resize the partition and then install by booting a DVD.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your disk uses a [Logical Disk Manager (LDM)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_Disk_Manager) configuration. This is Microsoft's proprietary version of a [logical volume management (LVM)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_volume_management) system. Unfortunately, Ubuntu can't be installed on an LDM disk -- at least, not using the standard installer. (It might be possible to hack it to work manually, but I've never tried it, and I don't know of any instructions to do so.)

The usual cause of this problem is creating more than four partitions in Windows. The standard Windows tools convert from a regular disk to an LDM setup when you do this, with an understated warning that most people ignore or don't even notice. Some people dig themselves into this hole by attempting to create Linux partition(s) within Windows. When installing Linux, it's OK to shrink the Windows partition in Windows, but you should ***never*** attempt to create Linux partitions using the standard Windows partitioning tools.

The solution is to convert back from LDM to a conventional MBR setup with primary, extended, and logical partitions. Some third-party partitioning tools can supposedly do this. IIRC, [EaseUS Partition Master](http://www.easeus.com/partition-manager/) is one of these, and I believe there's at least one other. I'm not 100% positive about EaseUS, though, so you may have to do a Web search to find suitable software.

Answer (score 0):

i find the solution to the problem;

i read a topic about similar problems,and i found some advices to use partitioning softwares , so i use a lot but no one was usefull ,until i find " AOMEI Partition Assistant Standard Edition 5.6", i try it and it find the problem,which was "dynamic disk problem"

and it advice me to use "Dynamic Disk Converter" to convert it  from "dynamic disk" to "basic disk".

i use it, and ...BANG !!! only 3 seconds and the problem was fixed.

---

So :

- install "AOMEI Partition Assistant Standard Edition 5.6" to see if
  you have the same problem.
- install and convert your disk to basic    disk using "Dynamic Disk
  Converter".
- use "AOMEI Partition    Assistant..." to manage your partitions.